# In shellscript, how to add +1 to a particular digit in a string

Tags: bash, shell

I have a set of many back-to-back systems, each named like m2001-1 which connects to s3001-1 and so on. here's a few for example: m2002-2 connects to s3002-2, m2003-3 connects to s3003-3, m2008-8 connects to s3008-8 (hope you can see the pattern, the m2/s3 is all that changes. m2* system doing the work, s3* is the system collecting the results)
I would like to figure out a way in bash shell-script to look at my current hostname (for example m2005-5) and +1 to the 2nd digit so that the script can figure out it's partner. I'm guessing some linux-foo sed/awk will be needed.
P.S. I realized after posting this that I would have to still change the letter... so I am thankful that the suggested solution works so easily to do both the numeric and letter change.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What have you tried so far?

Comment: At least put your data in a formatted format.

Comment: Can they ever be other than `m2` and `s3`? If not, you don't need to do addition, just a simple string replacement.

Answer (score 0):

Use the string replacement operator in [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion)

```
worker=m2002-2
collector=${worker/m2/s3}
echo "$collector"
```